# What is the difference between "teda" and "enua"?

Tags: word-meaning

*Teda* and *enua* both mean *boring*, don't they? What is the difference between the two?

And hmm... lernu also lists *enuiga*. What is the meaning of this one?

Answer (score 5):

**Beginner warning!** Anyone please fix me if I am wrong.

Based on examples from the Vortaro, I feel a distinction between them because they would translate to different words in my language (at least I think they would), but I find hard to express that using single word equivalents in English. I think *teda* is more towards being lengthy – boring or exhaustive because of duration and lack of proportionate amount of content – while *enua* has rather to do with emptiness and lack of interest or activity whatsoever. So a talk one finds *teda*, for example, could have been good if it was cut shorter. But one that's *enua* is a plain waste of time and was at no point interesting to the listener.

According to the same logic, waiting for someone's arrival for 3 hours would be *teda*. Being closed in an empty room with nothing to do for the same time would be *enua*.

I think the difference between *enua* and *enuiga* is (in this context) null. According to Vortaro again, the former includes the latter, but is more general in the sense that it could also describe other adjectival relations to boredom than just assigning the quality to a noun. Like in this sentence,

> mi iom amas en enua tempo tralegi ion amuzan,

in which I would understand "in a time of boredom": it's no longer boring when I fill it with the activity.

---

**Update**: Found in the [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/):

> tedi (tr): kaŭzi lacenon kaj malagrablecon pro **trodaŭro, troripetiĝo aŭ troabundo**
>
> enui (ntr): malplezuri pro **senintereso aŭ neokupiteco**

(emphasis mine). And an example where *enua ⊃ enuiga*:

> la princo oscedis kaj ĉirkaŭrigardis per enuaj okuloj (montrantaj enuon)

I think that supports all my above claims.

Comment: What do you mean with enua ⊃ enuiga? That enua can mean enuiga? Because to me, in the last phrase, his eyes are related to boredom but not boring. I think ≠ would be more correct here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the reta vortaro, **Teda** means something that makes you tired because of repetition. It is probably closer to the english word **tedious**.

> Kiu kaŭzas tedon, lacan incitiĝon pro daŭro, ripetiĝo, unutoneco: teda kiel kulo.

**Enua** means boring. **Enuiga** means something that forces boredom onto something else (probably a human or animal).

- Enu = this root means boardom.
- ig = to use force.
- a = adjective

Comment: If enui is intransitive then you can't have a direct object.

Comment: @Airvian You are right. I edited the answer. Such an example requires a preposition: Mi enuas pri li.